# Approximation of a distribution from $\mathcal{D}'$ by functions from $\mathcal{D}$

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation, distribution-theory

I need to  prove that for any generalized function ( they are also called distributions) $f \in \mathcal{D}'$ there exists generalized functions $f_n \in \mathcal{D} $, given by normal functions from $\mathcal{D},$ for which $$\langle f_n, \phi\rangle \rightarrow  \langle f, \phi\rangle \quad \forall \phi \in \mathcal{D}.$$

1. My idea was the following:
   I am able to prove that $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $\mathcal{D}'$ relatively *-weak convergence; after this it seemed obvious to me that we can simply take $f_n$ from this dense $\mathcal{D}$ with the condition 
   $$|\langle f_n, \phi\rangle -  \langle f, \phi\rangle| \leq 1/n,$$ and it will be the required sequence. But at this point I have a problem: this won't work because topology in $\mathcal{D}'$ can't be made metric;
2. Moreover, my teacher told me that for given $\phi$ we can find such $f_n$ that 
   $$|\langle f_n, \phi\rangle -  \langle f, \phi\rangle| \leq 1/n,$$ but it can't be done for all $\phi.$
3. Then I also tried to approximate $f$ by a finite function $g$ since they are also dense in $\mathcal{D}'$ but I faced the same problem: we can find the sequence for $g,$ but not for $f.$
4. I would be glad for any help!

Comment: Hint: Consider convolving your distribution with a smooth mollifier.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676109/limit-of-distribution-functions (class mate?)

Comment: I do know the problem of aproximating a generalised function f with regular functions - the answer is convolution of f with the standard averaging kernel ( it is hat-function that tends to Dirac delta-function); but the resulting functions are not finite, so they are not from D

Comment: You should try getting the properties you want in stages of approximations. From the hint, you have a sequence $g^{(k)}$ of smooth functions whose support is not compact such that $\langle g^{(k)}, \phi \rangle \to \langle f, \phi \rangle$. Then construct for each $k$ compactly supported smooth functions $f_n^{(k)}$ such $\langle f_n^{(k)}, \phi \rangle \to \langle g^{(k)}, \phi \rangle$ as $n \to \infty$. Finally check that $\langle f_n^{(n)}, \phi \rangle \to \langle f, \phi \rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\psi \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $\int \psi = 1$ and let $\psi_n(x) = n \psi(nx).$ Then $\psi_n \to \delta$ is a [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).

Also take $\rho \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $\rho(0)=1$ and let $\rho_n(x) = \rho(x/n).$ Then $\rho_n \to 1$ pointwise and in $\mathcal{E} = C^\infty.$

Let $F_n = \rho_n (\psi_n*F).$

Does $F_n \in \mathcal{D}$? Does $F_n \to F$ in $\mathcal{D}'$?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! F_n is indeed from D, and then we use the fact that the operation of convolution is continuous, and convolution of any function  with delta is that function, yes?

Comment: Sounds like a good way.

Comment: Sorry, but now  I am not sure that F_n is from D:  if I take  a hat-function omega_eps as a mollifier,  I understand that the support of F_n  is [-n-eps; n+eps] and convolution gives function from C^(infinity), but due to the fact that f is from D' , not from D, F_n also would not be from D; how can I fix this?

Comment: I've made a change, which should fix it.

Comment: That seems to work, thank you) but I am not sure I totally understand why F_n -> F; I mean that I understand why convolution tends to F, but this additional function rho_n makes me confused; I don't see why it -> 1 pointwise

Comment: I take a function that's smooth and has value $1$ at $x=0$ and then stretch it horizontally. Every point will then get a value close to $\rho(0)$ for big $n$.

Comment: And I hope that you understand that $\rho_n$ is multiplied with $\psi_n*F;$ it's not function application.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand it)