# Limit of distribution functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Let $D$ be a space of distribution functions. I need to prove that for any function $F \in D'$ there are distribution functions $F_n \in D$ for which $F_n(f) \rightarrow F(f)$ for every $f \in D$.  
I know how to prove $D$ is dense in $D'$ in weak-$*$ topology, but i don't know what to do next. I've tried to construct a sequence of $F_n$ using density of $D$, but my teacher said that we can't do this because $D'$ topology is not metrizable. Would be glad for any help.

Comment: @md2perpe why does the non-metrizability matter? I thought that $\mathcal{D}$ being weak-* dense in $\mathcal{D}'$ meant that for any $u\in\mathcal{D}'$, there exist $u_n\in\mathcal{D}$ so that $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $\mathcal{D}',$ i.e. $u_n(\varphi)\rightarrow u(\varphi)$ for all $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}.$ What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3):

Take $\psi \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $\int \psi = 1$ and let $\psi_n(x) = n \psi(nx).$ Then $\psi_n \to \delta$ is a [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).

Also take $\rho \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $\rho(0)=1$ and let $\rho_n(x) = \rho(x/n).$ Then $\rho_n \to 1$ pointwise and in $\mathcal{E} = C^\infty.$

Let $F_n = \rho_n (\psi_n*F).$

Does $F_n \in \mathcal{D}$? Does $F_n \to F$ in $\mathcal{D}'$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why $F_n \in D$? I couldn’t prove this myself.

Comment: I've made a change that should fix it.

Comment: But why does this function $p_n$ tends to 1 as n tends to infinity?

Comment: Pointwise, $\rho_n(x) = \rho(x/n) \to \rho(0) = 1$ as $n \to \infty.$ The continuity of $\rho$ implies that $\rho_n \to 1$ on every compact set, and thus in $C^\infty.$